# Enum.GetName vs Enum.ToString

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums, tostring

For this enumeration,

```
Enum MyEnum
    Value
End Enum
```

there are two methods to get the name representation `Value` of `MyEnum.Value`:

```
[Enum].GetName(GetType(MyEnum), MyEnum.Value) ' aka Enum.GetName
```

and

```
Dim a As MyEnum = MyEnum.Value
a.ToString ' aka Enum.ToString
```

What are their pros and cons? And which is better after all?

**PS:** There is [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291076/java-enum-why-use-tostring-instead-of-name) for java but this is .NET which may have different functionality.

Comment: `ToString` can handle enums with `Flag` attribute with multiple flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples of what can be done using this enum, note the usage of the flags attribute.

```
    <Flags>
   Public Enum bit As Short
        none = 0
        s0 = 1 << 0
        s1 = 1 << 1
        s2 = 1 << 2
        s3 = 1 << 3
        s4 = 1 << 4
        s5 = 1 << 5
        s6 = 1 << 6
        s7 = 1 << 7
        s8 = 1 << 8
        s9 = 1 << 9
        s10 = 1 << 10
        s11 = 1 << 11
        s12 = 1 << 12
        s13 = 1 << 13
        s14 = 1 << 14
        all = -1
    End Enum
```

and this code

```
    Dim s As String = bit.s13.ToString
    s = (bit.s10 Or bit.s11).ToString

    Dim foo() As String
    foo = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(bit))

    For Each s As String In foo
        Debug.WriteLine(s)
    Next

    Dim test As bit = bit.s1 Or bit.s3 Or bit.s5
    Debug.WriteLine(test.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine(CShort(test).ToString)

    test = test Or CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(bit), "s14"), bit)
    Debug.WriteLine(test.ToString)
```