# Doesn't the default Object.toString() append hashCode()?

Tags: java, enums, tostring, hashcode

I have an Enum class in Airport.java

```
package test;

public enum Airport {
    PHX,
    LAX,
    SFO,
    NRT,
    SIN;

    Airport() {
    }
}
```

and a Test class in Test.java

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Airport a = Airport.PHX;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(a));
        System.out.println(a.name());
        System.out.println(a.toString());
        System.out.println(a.name() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(a.hashCode()));
    }

}
```

The output for this is

```
PHX
PHX
PHX
PHX
PHX@15db9742
```

but shouldn't the output be

```
PHX
PHX
PHX
PHX@15db9742
PHX@15db9742
```

According the the Object API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html the default `Object.toString()` is `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Comment: An `enum` type implicitly extends the `Enum` class and is final.

Comment: Note that lines 1, 2 and 4 would be identical anyway. So if you expected the hashcode on 4, it should be present on 1 and 2 also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's indeed the default implementation of `toString()`. However, `java.lang.Enum`, the implicit base class for all `enum`s overrides `toString()` by returning its name.

Comment: Short and simple. Also, don't forget: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291076/java-enum-why-use-tostring-instead-of-name.

Comment: @MordechayS, that post was actually the original post that sent me down the rabbit hole looking for this.